# Twilio REST API: request messages after sid

Tags: twilio

## Problem

Using the Twilio REST API, I want to request only messages that I haven't downloaded yet.  It seems the cleanest way to do this would be to download only messages after a specified SID.

## Information not in the docs

The [Twilio filter docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sms#list-get-filters) don't have this option.  They only describe `to`, `from`, and `date_sent`.

However, it appears that Twilio does have this feature.  You can see in their [paging information](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/response#response-formats-list-paging-information), that the the `nextpageuri` contains `AfterSid`.

When browing the website, the URL contains `/user/account/log/messages?after=SMXXXXXX`

## What I've tried so far

Using the twilio-ruby client, I have tried the following without success:

`list = @client.account.sms.messages.list({after: 'SMXXXXXX'})`

`list = @client.account.sms.messages.list({AfterSid: 'SMXXXXXX'})`

`list = @client.account.sms.messages.list({after_sid: 'SMXXXXXX'})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Dan Markiewicz - Twilio Customer Support

> Unfortunately, we do not support filtering by this field in our API at this time. Your best option would be to get the DateCreated info on the SID you want to filter by and then use that to filter the messages by only those sent after that date. Since the date filter only supports filtering down to the day, it may return some number of unwanted messages that were sent that day but before the message you want to filter by. However, each message in the list will have a full date_created field down to the second, so you should be able to filter these out fairly easily on your end. This should produce the result you need.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the documentation you outlined, it looks like what you want to accomplish can't be done by the `twilio-ruby` gem. [This link](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby/blob/56a56c374b0462e6b03d1029a6d53a0b877f0785/docs/usage/messages.rst) shows which filters are supported by the list method inside the gem in regards to messages.

If you look at the source [here](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby/blob/34b552637e6e9661c829d68c10afe3c1fef4e886/lib/twilio-ruby/rest/list_resource.rb), starting on line 45 the gem uses `next_page_uri` as a way of determining the offset of where the next page should begin. For instance:

```
calls = twilio_client.account.calls.list # returns the initial set of calls.
calls.next_page # this uses next_page_uri to return the next set of calls internally.
```

This isn't something that can be changed via the gem currently.

Comment: Looking at [line 38 of the code you referenced](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby/blob/34b552637e6e9661c829d68c10afe3c1fef4e886/lib/twilio-ruby/rest/list_resource.rb#L38), it appears that the list can be filtered by passing URL parameters to `@client.get @path, params, full_path`, so the `list` method is pre-filtered. I just not sure which URL params Twilio supports here.

Comment: I believe the parameters you are able to pass into the `list` method  pertain to the ability to filter down the resource list, not pagination.  It's possible that they are also filtering these parameters out for those who use the API.  At this point I would open up an issue on the Github repository.  Someone should be able to help you there.